# GitHub - why two lines are marked as different without any visible differences?

Tags: git, github, diff, git-diff

Here's the [`commit cba438 on Github`](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/pull/235/commits/cba4383b9e3a2b6238d4e0e858d88d1d010fedd2?diff=unified#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3b).

As you can see line #1 in index.html is marked as changed:

[image]

But as I can see there's no single changed character. Is it up to GitHub or Git? Is it a bug or some hidden character was changed?

Comment: This could be line endings or possibly whitespace.  I think it is Git, GitHub is just a bystander here most likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a hidden character there, a [UTF8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

```
$ git show cba438:index.html | od -c | head -1
0000000 357 273 277   <   !   d   o   c   t   y   p   e       h   t   m
$ git show cba438~1:index.html | od -c | head -1
0000000   <   !   d   o   c   t   y   p   e       h   t   m   l   >  \n
```

---

Related SO question: [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223882/1331425)

Comment: Thank you Wumpus for the nice answer with the command line explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Looks like a whitespace at the end of the deleted line.

Comment: This is strange. I'm pretty sure that there were no trailing spaces in my code as I have `"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true` enabled in Sublime Text. Also, if it's the whitespace, shouldn't GitHub mark it like this: https://i.imgur.com/5KIR6fU.png